# How does one install this mcrypt package?

Tags: macos, installation, unix, terminal, libraries

I'm using MAC os x Mavericks, so after dlownload `mcrypt-2.6.8`, I decided to to configure ( per the recommendation of a dozen blogs ) like so :

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 CFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking
```

I do just `./configure` it builds fine with no errors, but none of the methods are accessible when I try to use mcrypt. So I assume its because I didn't do that big, long, stringy ./configure is the reason why it's not working.

However!

If I do use that long stringy ./configure, it returns this at the end of the ./configure :

```
*** Could not run libmcrypt test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means LIBMCRYPT was incorrectly installed
*** or that you have moved LIBMCRYPT since it was installed. In the latter case, you
*** may want to edit the libmcrypt-config script: /usr/local/bin/libmcrypt-config
configure: error: *** libmcrypt was not found
```

Hmm.. that's strange. Why can't it find my libmcrypt? I just installed it and made sure I opened a new terminal window. What could I be missing?